# How to query using ← / back arrow / asignment / naming / renaming / declaration

Tags: relational-algebra

> Student(id, name, address, city, birthYear)
>   Course(code, courseName, lengthWeeks, institution°)
>   Institution(instNr, instName, instCity)
>   Takes(id°, code°)
>
> List the ids and names of students who do not take the Databases course.
>
> t1 ← σ courseName=Databases (Course)
>   t2 ← t1 ⋈ Takes
>   t3 ← t2 ⋈ Student
>   t4 ← π id, name (t3)
>   t5 ← π id, name (Student)
>   R ← t5 \ t4

I don't understand the logic behind t5. How can you pick id's and names that are already removed from the relation? Could you do it another way with the ¬?

Comment: The operators of the relational algebra returns new relations. So each `ti` is a new relation, and the original relations are not modified.

Comment: What is `¬`? Do you mean ``\``? If you mean `not` for use in `restrict`/`select` then you need to give a reference to or definition of the "relational algebra" you are using so we know it's allowed. Also you should explain `°`. Note that marking individual attributes is in general inadequate to show CKs & FKs because they can have multiple attributes & there can be multiple ones per relation value/variable. Also because a FK can reference multiple tables & FK column names can reference differently named columns. Also note that constraints (including PKs, CKs, FKs, etc) are not needed to query.

Answer (score 0):

RA (relational algebra) operators return values given input relation values. (As with everyday addition for integers.) They don't change or establish the values associated with names of variables or constants. That's outside an algebra. The only way a name might get associated with a new value is if your `←` is defined to be variable assignment rather than constant declaration. You have to tell us that. Either way it's not a relational algebra operator. It is a symbol in a language whose expressions include more than just names denoting relations (terminals) and nested algebra operator calls (non-terminals). We can in a certain sense consider it an operator of that language but it is not an operator of the algebra. And either way your code never associates a second value with the same name.

(Some RAs have operators that input names as well as relation values in order to disambiguate inputs. But using such input names to associate variable/constant names with values on output is not a RA operation.)

(A RA could define its notion of relation as containing a name and a set of tuples, so it could have an algebraic renaming operator that takes a name and a relation and returns a relation with the given name in its name part. But again that would not affect the value associated with any variable/constant name used to identify the input relation.)

Re "do it another way": Usually we assume some RA operators & some way to name relation values, and then there is an obvious set of query expressions: We take an expression that is a name to denote its associated value and we take an expression that is an operator call to denote the value of calling the operator on the values of its argument expressions. (As with everyday integer arithmetic expressions.)

But a particular query language although *defined in terms of* such expressions might not actually allow you to *write* any or all such expressions. (Eg relational tuple calculus & domain calculus.) And/or it might define additional expressions in terms of expression rearrangement without explicitly giving a corresponding operator.

(Some presentations of relational algebras confuse RA operators with expressions of a query language inspired by RA. Then there might be query expressions whose results depend on the variable/constant names that appear as arguments, rather than just the values named by the names that appear as arguments. Then there can be query expressions that you might not be able to write via a nesting of operator calls and that might need you to associate a value with a name via assignment/declaration.)