# joining tables in relational algebra, what happens to the attributes which have the same name?

Tags: database, relational-algebra

[the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLKl0.jpg)

I am trying to join the Employee and Customer tables, but what happens to the attributes which have the same name, because they are storing data that isn't the same?

Maybe both are kept and you can access them doing Employee.Name or Customer.Name.

Comment: Please: Give all but only what you need to ask your question & relate it to your problem. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: This is not clear. What does "happens to the attributes" mean? Or "storing data that isn't the same" or "both are kept"? Also: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & a reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Show parts you can do. Explain re how you are 1st stuck/unsure. [ask] [Help] [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: [Some presentations of relational algebras confuse RA operators with expressions of a query language inspired by RA.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104417/3404097)